# How to display the sum of all rows for a given person

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I am trying to write an SQL query to display the amount of each user's input of certain values.

Below are the tables that I am using in MySQL. These tables do not contain any FK, only PK for performance purposes.

Table LIST_DETAILS:

[image]

Table USERS:

[image]

Table DISPOSITIONS:

[image]

Below is the SQL query that I have tried. The issue I'm having is that it only shows ONE user, not the 250 users I am expecting.

```
select job_name, concat(fname,' ',lname),  
       sum(disposition_category = 'Attempts') as Attempts,
       sum(disposition_category = 'RPC') as RPC,
       sum(disposition_category = 'Contacts') as Contacts,
       sum(disposition_category = 'Voted') as Voted,
       sum(disposition_category = 'RPC and Voted') as 'RPC and Voted',
       sum(disposition_category = 'Other') as Other,
       sum(disposition_category = 'Directory Assistance') as 'Directory Assistance'
from list_details ld
     join users u ON u.id = ld.id
     join dispositions d ON d.id = u.id
where security_level = 1;
```

This is the output I want to see, however it is only showing one user when I need to see 250 displayed.

```
|       job_name         | concat(fname,' ',lname) | Attempts | RPC | Contacts | Voted | RPC and Voted | Other | Directory Assistance |
| SPDR-lower-range8-8-14 |      Rosybel Abreu      |    11    | 10  |    7     |   0   |      0        |   9   |         1           |
```

Can anyone help me correct my mistake?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the `11` attempts is for all employees, and not just the one shown above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having here is because `SUM()` is an aggregate function, that sums over an entire group.

You're summing the entire group of employees into one row. You need to add a `GROUP BY` clause so that MySQL knows which groups to sum the values for. In this case, I think you want to group by user id, so try this:

```
SELECT job_name, CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) AS name,  
   SUM(disposition_category = 'Attempts') as Attempts,
   SUM(disposition_category = 'RPC') AS RPC,
   SUM(disposition_category = 'Contacts') AS Contacts,
   SUM(disposition_category = 'Voted') AS Voted,
   SUM(disposition_category = 'RPC and Voted') AS 'RPC and Voted',
   SUM(disposition_category = 'Other') AS Other,
   SUM(disposition_category = 'Directory Assistance') AS 'Directory Assistance'
FROM list_details ld
JOIN users u ON u.id = ld.id
JOIN dispositions d ON d.id = u.id
WHERE security_level = 1
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: I think it should group by job_name as well, but basically this is correct.

Comment: I feel so dumb. but it is only pulling 45 rows, i should have around 243. So does that mean it could be my join statements?

Comment: It could be. A good test would be to select everything from your joins, and see how many rows are returned that way. Are you sure you have 243 actual users? Or is it 45 users who span those 243 rows?

Comment: @evanv it's possible, but the way this is designed I don't think a user can have more than one job_name. It looks like a 1-1 relationship to me.

Comment: Yes i am sure that it is 243, i just did a select count.

Comment: Do a select count but group by user id and see how many rows are returned.

Comment: @AznDevil92 if all else fails, can you post say 10 rows of sample data and your expected results for those 10 rows and maybe we can work it out on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Just reviewed my data and spoke to my manager, it is actually 45 users, the other 200 are not active. I guess that is the reason it is not being shown. Thank you for all your help!